# View SMS Messages After Removing SIM

Tags: iphone

If I remove the SIM from an iPhone, then will I be able to view the SMS Messages that I sent and received while the SIM card was in the phone after I take the SIM card out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Just to confirm this, I took the SIM card out of my own iPhone 6S and all SMS texts were present.